# Brackets Freezing On Load Due To Git-Integration Plugin

Tags: javascript, git, github, brackets

Brackets is my main code editor and recently I installed the git-integration plugin on it. Now when I try to open Brackets, it freezes up as the new plugin tries to load in.

At the bottom of the screen I can see it picking up a bunch of android files, even though I have yet to work on an Android project on this computer.

I have not changed any settings in the plugin and now it has gotten to a point where I can't even open extension manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- simply uninstall everything (including Brackets itself), resintall Brackets/then Git Plugins (as in [issue 12897](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12897))
- try deleting the [Brackets cache folder](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Cache-Folder) ([issue 1323](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/issues/1323#issuecomment-260211157))
  [image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1067319/20248709/c158a4c6-aa3d-11e6-82ef-4f7c3c6fce07.png]
- check the developer tools log ([issue 1323](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/issues/1323#issuecomment-260561975))